# Prevent tampering of JavaScript values

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, mastercard

I'm implementing a MasterCard payment gateway to a website.
In the official guide, JavaScript is used to pass the amount to be charged, and to which merchant the money goes to.

It looks like a user can potentially change any of the values and have the gateway return a success message back to us.

Even the success message doesn't seem to have much details for revalidation.

I can't think of a way to prevent this other than somehow converting the JavaScript to server-side code.

Official guide:
https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

Comment: My bad. It does have a built in anti temper thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution on this.
From https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

you can find the section **Obtain the Payment Result**.
You would see when creating the checkout_session, you need to input parameter **amount** (*not compulsory in API documentation).

The line: `-d "order.amount=100.00" \`

so that when you put the session id in:

```
Checkout.configure({
...
       session: { 
            id: "SESSION000292090496253818604576"
       },
...
});
```

what you say "potentially change any of the values" would be prevented.

**Summary**: just add `amount` parameter in your server-side code when obtaining session id.